# Custom NSManagedObject setter in category

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have placed all of my NSManagedObject's custom logic in a category, so that I can regenerate the standard classes from my model if an when it changes.

One such piece of logic I require is a custom setter on one of the object's properties:

```
- (void) setName:(NSString *)name
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"name"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:name forKey:@"name"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"name was changed");//for example
}
```

I have placed this in the category, which in this case is `Item+Custom.m`

My question:

Why is it that, whenever I set the name of an Item, it is **not** necessary to import Item+Custom.m? The log statement above still fires.

Just curious how the class sending the message doesn't need to know about the category for the logic to still fire?

And (perhaps a separate issue) what would happen if I added the same custom setter, with a different logging statement, to a second category on the same object?

Comment: Is your category declared in you model's `.h` file?

Comment: No - assuming you mean 'is it declared in the .h generated by core data'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a program is loaded, all category methods are made known to the runtime. So if you declare a `-[Item setName:]` method, then Core Data will not create this method at runtime anymore.

You need not import anything because `name` is already declared as a `@dynamic` property in the Xcode generated managed object subclass files.

If two categories declare the same method, or if the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method in the original class, the behavior is undefined, see [Avoid Category Method Name Clashes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW4) in "Programming with Objective-C".